# Stretching my Jquery slideshow to fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So im trying to stretch my Jquery slideshow to fit the whole browser and im having a difficulty getting it to work I downloaded the jquery vegas plugin but I cant seem to find the problem I want my slide show to look like the one on www.dealix.com thanks!

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#fadein {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}

#fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;

#vegas-loading {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    background: url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center; /* Loading Gif by http://preloaders.net/ */
    height: 32px;
    left: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    width: 32px; 
    z-index: 0;
}

#vegas-overlay {
    background: transparent url(overlays/01.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -1;
}

#vegas-background {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
    max-width: none !important; /* counteracts global img modification by twitter bootstrap library */
    z-index: -2;
}

#vegas-overlay,
#vegas-background {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}

-->
</style>


</head>

<body>


    <div class="fadein">
    <img src="images/slide.jpg">
   <img src="images/slide1.jpg"> 

</div>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="JqueryPlugins/jquery.vegas"></script>
<script src="JqueryPlugins/jquery.vegas.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn()
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ..just read the docs and you'll get it done, that's what I did and it worked! look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YvZS/), here at the [docs](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/slideshow/), images from [Gratisography](http://www.gratisography.com/).

You only need the css and js files, and a function like this one:

```
$(function() {
    var backgrounds = [
        "http://www.gratisography.com/pictures/110.jpg",
        "http://www.gratisography.com/pictures/111.jpg",
        "http://www.gratisography.com/pictures/112.jpg"
    ];

    $.vegas('slideshow', {
      backgrounds:[
        { src: backgrounds[0], fade:1000 },
        { src: backgrounds[1], fade:1000 }
      ]
    })('overlay');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you only need either jquery.vegas.js or jquery.vegas.min.js (which is just the minified version) and you should put these along with jQuery.js in the `<head>` tag.

You need to also download the [jquery.vegas.min.css](http://kaysalvat.githib.io/vegas/releases/latest/jquery.vegas.min.css) and include it, use it instead of your css.

Finally you don't set the slideshow images in your html you set them in the vegas script directly:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.vegas( 'slideshow', {
                backgrounds:[
                  { src:'/images/slide.jpg', fade:1000, valign:'bottom' },
                  { src:'/images/slide1.jpg', fade:1000, valign:'bottom' }
                ]
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/setup/).